# Что такое public IEnumerable SomeName() ?

Tags: c#, интерфейс

Здравствуйте. Очень часто вижу в интернете подобный код:

```
public IEnumerable<Values> SomeName() {
//здесь какой-то код, неважно
}
```

Что делает IEnumerable<Values>? Почему не List<Values>? Или такой пример:

```
public static void printFamily(List<People> fam)
        {
            foreach (People p in fam)
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", p.Name, p.Age);
        }
```

Если заменить List<People> на IEnumerable<People>, то все по-прежнему работает. Что делает IEnumerable в "объявлении методов"? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

когда вы используете **не** IEnumerable<T>, то вы не можете сделать вот так:

```
public IEnumerable<int> SomeName() {
     foreach(var i in Enumerable.Range(0,3)){
          yield return i;    
     }
}
```

или даже так:

```
public IEnumerable<int> SomeName() {
    yield return 1;
    yield return 2;
    yield return 3;
}
```

Comment: @Spectre, уже понимаю) А если метод получает IEnumerable<T> в качестве параметра, вместо List<T>, то в чем разница?

Comment: когда уже здесь обсуждалось это, в кратце суть в том, что если метод принимает в качестве аргумента `IEnumerable<T>`, то в этот метод вы можете передать любой объект реализующий этот интерфейс, будь то `List<T>`, `Stack<T>`, `Queue<T>` или что либо другое. тоже самое и с возвращаемыми значениями

Comment: @Spectre, вроде понял все, спасибо за объяснение!

Answer (score 5):

**IEnumerable** - интерфейс, методы которого используются для описания как переходить от одного элемента к следующему, т.е. перечислитель. **foreach** как раз и использует его для прогулки по элементам. По-сути коллекции не реализующие **IEnumerable** не могут использоваться в **foreach**.

Comment: Да, но во втором моем примере, если оставить List<People>, то IEnumerable все равно можно пользоваться. Не понимаю)

Comment: List наследует IEnumerable. Можете создать свою коллекцию не наследующую IEnumerable и ничего не выйдет.

Comment: @Raskilas, понятно, спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx